# Windows complains on boot that GoogleCrashHelper is a 16-bit application

Tags: windows-7, windows

Whenever I start Windows, it complains that it cannot start Google Crash Helper, because it's a 16-bit application. Quite apart from the fact that I find that ludicrously unlikely, I also can't find any reference to `GoogleCrashHelper.exe` in the registry to begin with. What does the error actually mean, and how can I make it go away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you managed to solve this problem, and you're right that it does seem strange - possibly some kind of corruption in the executable.

To remove it from startup you could use Sysinternals' [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902). It should show up somewhere there, as Autoruns has quite an extensive list of locations it examines for startup applications.

[image]